# Can Apache Tika extract text from password protected Office documents?

Tags: microsoft-office, encryption

Can I run Tika from command line and extract text from a bunch of Microsoft Office documents that are encrypted with the same password? Googled for it, but not sure if it can or cannot be done.

Comment: Do you know the password?  What version of Office?  Is this doc, docx, or odt?

Comment: @PatrickM Yes, I know the password. The files are a mix of DOCX, XLSX, PPTX and PDF

Comment: OK，I missed the Tika.